# self.tableView.reloadData() not Calling cellForRowAtIndexPath() Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/files/")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
let array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray
files = []
for element in array {
    let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((element as! String).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    files.append(File(fileName: dict["name"] as! String, body: dict["body"] as! String))
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.myRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
})
task.resume()
```

The line `self.tableView.reloadData()` does not call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. `self.TableView` is not nil, and the table view reloads when I exit it and go back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call reloadData from the main thread. Use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.myRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

in the spot where you were calling reloadData and refreshControl.